# Why not bring any of these characters back with Hakan's blood?

Tags: the-protector

In the second season,

> Leyla

is turned into an Immortal, killed by another Immortal using their standard method, and brought back using their blood. Then she is forced to try to kill Hakan, who kills her with the dagger. That's all pretty terrible, but since the Protector's blood, drawn with the dagger, can revive Immortals, and Hakan has both, why not revive her that way (or at least try)? We definitely know that being killed by another Immortal is hardly an obstacle here (because Okhan could come back).

Similarly, in the fourth season, Faysal kills

> Vizier

using the standard method. Now, Hakan and company do not seem to be too happy about her death, so why not try to use his blood to revive her? If they had any scruples about it in the second season, they certainly have lost them by now.

Finally,

> Aylin is killed by Zeynep

again, with the usual method. Everyone is upset, because this means they cannot try to bring Aylin back to herself. But again, she was an Immortal when she was killed, so why not try using the blood of the Protector?

Along the same lines, we know that an Immortal can kill another Immortal who was once mortal using the standard method, then  bring them back to life using their own blood as if they were a regular mortal. Why would this not work on her?

In short, knowing what we know about the properties of Hakan's blood when drawn with the dagger, why was it not considered as an option in any of these cases?